# How to enter conditional list of headers in cell sorted based on cell values in same header's column?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, conditional-statements

In MS Excel, I'm trying to provide a list of headers in one cell based on if a header has a value (greater than 0). I hope to also sort the list in this cell by largest first. How can I do this?

I haven't learned Visual Basic at all, and have only really tried using some if statements. I have a very large table to sort out, and do not want to do this by hand.

What I'm trying to get:

```
         ---------  Header1   Header2   Header3   List
                    Apple     Orange    Pear  

Row 1 -     Ryan    0         0         0         --
Row 2 -     Cindy   0         5         7         Pears, Oranges
Row 3 -     Tom                                   N/A
Row 4 -     Jess    3         6         2         Oranges, Apples, Pears
```

Thank you!

Comment: Only possible with a formula if you have office 365 excel or later.

Comment: @Scott Craner: You can do that with a formula with classic excel as well, see answer below.

Comment: @Kaiser it can but see my comment to you on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Office 365 Excel you would use this Array Formula:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,INDEX($B$1:$D$1,N(IF({1},MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,7,$B3:$D3/($B3:$D3>0),ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,COUNTIF($B3:$D3,">0")))),$B3:$D3,0))))),IF(COUNT(B3:D3)>1,"---","N/A"))
```

Being an Array Formula one must confirm it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

It builds an array of the headers in order and returns it to the TEXTJOIN function.  One note though, if there is a tie in the values it will return the same header for both.  For Example `6,6,6` will return `Apple,Apple,Apple`.

[image]

---

If one does not have Office 365 Excel then put this code in a module attached to the worksheet and use the formula as stated above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

---

It can also be done by creating a sting one word at a time:

```
=MID(IF(B3>0,","&$B$1,"")&IF(C3>0,","&$C$1,"")&IF(D3>0,","&$D$1,""),2,999)
```

But this gets really unruly if there are many columns:

[image]

Comment: I'm not returning a list with the Office 365 array formula. I'm only getting the largest item of the list. How did you get yours to do this?

Great variety of answers btw!

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode?  When you did that did Excel put `{}` around the formula?

Comment: Ahh, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with old excel versions but the formula gets a bit complicated in order to show the proper commas in the right spot. I've separated in 2 formulas to make it clearer:

[image]

The first formula is to find and write the headers (located in column E):

```
 =+IF(COUNTIF(B6:D6,">"&0)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(B6>0,B$4&",",""),IF(C6>0,C$4&",",""),IF(D6>0,D$4,"")),"")
```

The second one is to clean the commas and provides the final result (located in column F):

```
=+IF(RIGHT(E6,1)=",",LEFT(E6,LEN(E6)-1),E6)
```

You can merge both in one but then it's difficult to clarify what the formula does:

```
=+IF(RIGHT(IF(COUNTIF(B6:D6,">"&0)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(B6>0,B$4&",",""),IF(C6>0,C$4&",",""),IF(D6>0,D$4,"")),""),1)=",",LEFT(IF(COUNTIF(B6:D6,">"&0)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(B6>0,B$4&",",""),IF(C6>0,C$4&",",""),IF(D6>0,D$4,"")),""),LEN(IF(COUNTIF(B6:D6,">"&0)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(B6>0,B$4&",",""),IF(C6>0,C$4&",",""),IF(D6>0,D$4,"")),""))-1),IF(COUNTIF(B6:D6,">"&0)>0,CONCATENATE(IF(B6>0,B$4&",",""),IF(C6>0,C$4&",",""),IF(D6>0,D$4,"")),""))
```

Comment: two things, this gets quite large if there is more than 3 columns and second, the OP asked to have the headers in order of the value not order of the header.  Just an FYI,  If the OP has only 3-4 items and does not care about order then this will work great.

Comment: I totally agree, putting them on order or adding more columns would be unbearable in a single formula.

Comment: Also if I was to do it with older string formula: `=MID(IF(B5>0,","&$B$4,"")&IF(C5>0,","&$C$4,"")&IF(D5>0,","&$D$4,""),2,999)`  See my edited answer below

Answer (score -1):

welcome to Stack Overflow!

Try checking out [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) to join cells together into a list. Also check out this link on [conditionally concatenating a range](https://www.howtoexcel.org/formulas/how-to-conditionally-concatenate-a-range-formula/) for a good example of implementation. Good luck!